# How to style trade mark with heading

Tags: html, css, size, tm

My Heading should look like this.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yUah.png)

When I use the span and reduce the size TM my picture then looks like this,
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw2EZ.png)

TM does not stand up, as the first picture
How to fix that?

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Do you have code?

Comment: You should describe the goal in the message itself, with words. It is unclear whether you really want to have the “TM” letters much smaller and thinner than the normal text in the heading and how they should be aligned. You should also show the code you used in order to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sup`. Or if you use `&trade;` it should align to the top. But if you're using the letters "TM" and adjusting the `font-size` then you can either use `vertical-align` or a `flex` layout with `align-items`.

```css
.flex span, .inline span {
  font-size: .5em;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.inline span {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<p>Text <sup>&trade;</sup></p>
<p>Text <span>&trade;</span></p>
<p class="flex">Text <span>TM</span></p>
<p class="inline">Text <span>TM</span></p>
```

Comment: Tnx again Michael,